# Simplify or Solve in term of some expressions (again)

Tags: simplifying-expressions, code-request

Suppose x=a, y=ad-bc, z=ade-bce-fga

Obviously, z = (ad-bc)e-(fg)a = e(y)-fg(x)

I want to get the output to be z = e(y)-fg(x)

I have tried Solve[{x==a, y==ad-bc, z==ade-bce-fga},z,{a,b,c,d}]

as some people suggest the code by eliminating the unwanted variables

for me but it doesn't work. Any idea for coding this or some nice built-in expression.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Note that `ad` is not the same thing as `a*d` or `a d` (with space being an implicit times). So do: `In[60]:= Solve[{x == a, y == a*d - b*c, 
  z == a*d*e - b*c*e - f*g*a}, {z}, {a, b, c, d}]

Out[60]= {{z -> -f g x + e y}}`

Comment: This is a variation on the theme of your previous question. `Eliminate[{x == a, y == a*d - b*c, z == a*d*e - b*c*e - f*g*a}, {a, b,
   c, d}]` almost does the job, resulting in `e y - z == f g x`.

Answer (score 0):

```
eq = {x == a, y == a d - b c, z == a d e - b c e - f g a};
Solve[Eliminate[eq, {a, b, c, d}], z]

{{z -> -f g x + e y}}
```